# how to make custom close/minimize/maximize menu dock on the right/left windows 10 screen

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jmenubar

How can I make the custom menu of close/minimize/maximize act like the default one ?

The Default menu can be docked on the right/left of the screen like split the screen on two parts , is there a way to make that happen ?

***The Default windows 10 menu picture :***

[image]

Comment: We don't write code from scratch. Show us what've you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the custom menu of close/minimize/maximize act like the default one ?

You create buttons and add an `Action` to each button.

1. for the "close" `Action` you would use the `dispose()` method on the frame
2. for the "minimize/maximum" `Actions` you would use the `setExtendedState(...)` method on the frame